# Is there a formula for the sequence: $1,1, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4}$ ...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to prove that there exists a sequence $a_{n}$ such that its partial limits are: $\{\frac{1}{n}\space|\space n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$. I thought about the following sequence:
$$
1,1, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4}\ldots 
$$

But I'm having a hard time to find an explicit formula for it.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. Specifically, just posting a question without any of your own work will be poorly received here.

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks, I edited it with more context.

Comment: It looks like the reciprocal of [A002260](https://oeis.org/A002260)

Comment: Please show your own work(what have you tried to justify your sequence, etc.).

Comment: To "prove that there exists ..." you do not need an explicit formula.

Comment: @GEdgar: Most anyone, if presented with such a formula, would probably wind up writing out the terms as shown in the question in order to see whether it works. I guess if one wants to show that a certain type of formalization is possible (e.g. does the series have certain algebraic-recursive properties), or if one needs to format it for some kind of software coding use, then a formula might be helpful, but not for a person trying to answer the question that is asked.

Comment: If you _really_ need a rigorous way of doing it, you could try writing a computer code that generates that sequence and then write down the pseudocode. But honestly just writing the sequence the way you have here will almost certainly be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use search for the sequence
$$ 1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots $$
in the OEIS which turns up
the [OEIS sequence A002260](https://oeis.org/A002260)

> Triangle read by rows: T(n,k) = k for n >= 1, k = 1..n.

One of the formulas given is

> n-th term is n - m*(m+1)/2 + 1, where m = floor((sqrt(8*n+1) - 1) / 2).

In other words

> a(n) = n - binomial(floor((1+sqrt(8*n))/2), 2).

Your sequence is the reciprocal of this sequence.